# Imagem se sobrepõe com menu aberto

Tags: css, imagem, menu, sass

Boa noite a todos. Estou fazendo meu portfólio, e percebi que quando abro o menu lateral, uma imagem se sobrepõe. Desse jeito:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está meu CSS (fiz ele com o Sass):

```
.sessao-formacoes {
background-color: #363636;
width: 100%;
height: 105.3vh;

.formacoes-header {
    h1 {
        font-family: $fonte-primaria;
        color: #fcfcfc;
        font-size: 2.5rem;
        text-align: center;
        padding-top: 2rem;
        padding-bottom: 2rem;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
}

.formacoes {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

    .card {
        width: 25rem;
        height: 25rem;
    }

    .card-imagem {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border-radius: 0.5rem;

        img {
            object-fit: contain;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: .9;
        }
    }

    .card-info {
        text-align: center;

        h2 {
            font-family: $fonte-primaria;
            color: #fcfcfc;
            padding-top: 0.5rem;
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
        }

        h3 {
            font-family: $fonte-secundaria;
            color: #f3f3f3;
            padding-bottom: 1rem;
        }

        p {
            font-family: $fonte-acao;
            color: #e7e7e7;
            padding-bottom: .2rem;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Alguém pode me ajudar? Não consegui descobrir o porque isso acontece.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Olá, uma solução simples seria usar o **z-index** com valor maior para o menu lateral e inseri-lo nos demais componentes com um valor menor; dessa forma o menu ficará sempre na frente das imagens quando este estiver aberto.

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente.